# NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem always YES on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, nslocale, metric-system

I am trying to decide if the users Region/Locale settings validates the use of Metric values (in this case if *kg* or *lb* should be appended).

I am running 3.2 on my iPad and on the simulator(Xcode 3.2.4). 
I have tried out a few different Region settings but I simply can not make it return `NO` for `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem`

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale systemLocale]; 
BOOL usesMetric = [[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];

NSLog(@"The system is Metric: %@\n", (usesMetric ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

This even happens for language set to **English** and region set to **United States** on both the simulator and on the actual device.

I also tried `NSLocaleMeasurementSystem` and it too always returns "Metric", never "U.S.".

How will I go about deciding if I should use Metric or not?

Thanks for any help given:)

*...could I be so lucky that the whole world changed to metric while I was sleeping:)*

Comment: I encountered the same issue, with no solution so far.

Answer (score 12):

Try `currentLocale` instead of `systemLocale`

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Because the question is almost a year old I found a workaround a long time ago, but never a cause. Can anyone confirm this is correct so I can accept the answer:)

Comment: systemLocale contains the default values in the absence of another value, i.e. the values in currentLocale. currentLocale is what you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, until I realized, that **UK officially uses metric system**. I have always thought that they still use imperial, so I tested with UK.

As soon as I started to test US locale, NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem started to return "NO" as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to be right! do you have any source for the UK officially using metric?

Comment: Pretty much only North America uses the Imperial system. The rest of the work uses metric.